# TestMethod in c# for JSON data check from ASP .NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, assert

Please tell me how to get the value by not changing the controller action.

```
Controller
     [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult A_Action_In_Controller(Guid ID)
        {
            var operationConfirmation = _repository.DoSomethingInDB(emailID);

            return Json(new { operationConfirmation }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
Test Method
    [TestMethod]
        public void DoSomethingInDB_SendOperationConfirmationToTheUI()
        {... 
                var expected = "Successfully Completed";

            var target = controller.A_Action_In_Controller(obj1.Id);

            Assert.AreEqual(expected, target.Data);

        }
```

Error

> ```
> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Successfully Completed (System.String)>. Actual:<{ operationConfirmation = Successfully
> ```
>
> Completed } (<>f__AnonymousType2`1[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]])>.

Please tell me how to write something like 
`Assert.AreEqual(expected, target.Data.operationConfirmation);`

instead of what I am having now, i dont want to change my controller code

`Assert.AreEqual(expected, target.Data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller is changed to

```
Controller
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult A_Action_In_Controller(Guid ID)
    {
        var operationConfirmation = _repository.DoSomethingInDB(emailID);

        return Json(operationConfirmation, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Then test method works well

```
  [TestMethod]
    public void DoSomethingInDB_SendOperationConfirmationToTheUI()
    {... var expected = "Operation failed";         


        var target = controller.A_Action_In_Controller(obj1.Id);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, target.Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize the JSON string, the below uses the `JavaScriptSerializer` class:

First, name your confirmation in your `A_Action_In_Controller` method, like so:

```
return Json(new { confirmation = operationConfirmation }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then do this in your test method:

```
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var deserializedTarget = (object[])js.DeserializeObject(target.Data.ToString());
var result = (string)deserializedTarget["confirmation"];
```

Then you can do:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
```

Comment: hi I am getting compilation error by using your solution and after modifying it then exception is occurring e.g. Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (16): { confirmation = Successfully Completed }

Comment: i have changed it to var deserializedTarget = (object[])js.DeserializeObject(target.Data.ToString());

Comment: Wrap Successfully Completed into quotes, like `{ confirmation = "Successfully Completed" }`

Comment: Do you mean return Json(new { confirmation = "\""+operationConfirmation+"\""}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); i dont think this is a good idea

Comment: Ah sorry no, I thought you had that string hard coded without quotes. Is it working?

Comment: Unfortunately not, that ArgumentException still exists

Comment: just say how to get my desired value out of this string. { confirmation = Successfully Completed }

Comment: i get above result from this line of code var dataInString = target.Data.ToString();

Comment: @Shantu Check my updated edit, you need to do `js.DeserializeObject(target.Data)` **NOT** just `target`. My fault, I thought it was a string, it's a JsonResult.

Comment: I have already done this and sent you that line of code, just check my second comment above or i am coping it again  var deserializedTarget = (object[])js.DeserializeObject(target.Data.ToString());